# CSS display: none; not working in Firefox. How can I fix this?

Tags: css, wordpress, cross-browser

I have a website which was created by someone else and I have been tasked with taking over. On this website there was a sandwich style menu and a search bar in the navigation.

I have since created a mega menu (WordPress Plugin). Now the older icons are redundant and useless therefore I have applied a `display: none;` rule to the CSS to remove them from the frontend.

This works correctly on Safari and Chrome on Mac however it seems as though Windows users on Firefox and Chrome as well as users of Firefox on Mac can still see the icons.

Can anyone help? The website is [www.quanser.com](https://www.quanser.com). You will see the icons in the header to the right.

```
header.site-header .badge-links {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Did you clear Autoptimize's cache after adding this new CSS rule?

Comment: Try clearing browser cache.

Comment: css you posted looks ok. Probably a caching issue as mentioned by the other ppl **or** you have that CSS in a file that is conditionally loaded, because I cannot see it in FF.

Comment: Clearing the Autoptimize cache seemed to do it thanks for that I didn't think I had to do it everytime I guess I should get into that habit :)

Comment: Thank you everyone for the quick response! Thanks @cabrerahector

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Firefox on Windows and still can see the Search and Hamburger menu icon (my first time visiting your site), this means this has nothing to do with cache. Though usually working with Wordpress, you should clear the cache after changing some CSS.

So far, I've inspected the CSS and see that this CSS block is repeated 3 times, which the last block will look like:

```
.header.site-header .badge-links {
   position: absolute;
   top: -3px;
   right: -.625rem;
}
```

Try to find this block in your CSS, and add something like this:

```
.header.site-header .badge-links {
   position: absolute;
   top: -3px;
   right: -.625rem;
   display: none; 
}

You don't need to `!important` in your CSS in this case.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty efficient way for solving this:

```
header.site-header .badge-links {
    z-index:-100;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
header.site-header .badge-links {
    z-index:100;
}
@
}
```